# How do I configure Entity Framework to use whatever database is in the connection string

Tags: database, frameworks, entity, configure

The code I inherited has an `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` , and inside that method , for each entity, it does `entity.ToTable("someTableName", "someDatabaseName");`

Instead of specifying "someDatabaseName" in `entity.ToTable("someTableName", "someDatabaseName");`   how do I configure EF to use whatever db is inside the connection string?

One solution is to go inside `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` and make the string "someDatabaseName" into a variable, then set that variable based on the connection string,  (but something about that seems wonky , and leaves me wondering what is a better, more preferred way?)

```
//This code runs before OnModelCreating()
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(_connectionString);   
        //I wrongly assume the context would be using the db from this conn string, 
        //but it's not, it's using the database "someDatabaseName" from OnModelCreating below
    }
}
        
        
//after OnConfiguring, then this code runs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.2.4-servicing-10062");
    modelBuilder.Entity<SomeClass>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("table1", "someDatabaseName");   //i could make "someDatabaseName a variable, but surely there is a better way?
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change this

```
entity.ToTable("table1", "someDatabaseName");
```

to this

```
entity.ToTable("table1");
```